# Insert user defined time point in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, insert

I want to use some specified time points in my data. I have used `new Date('Dec 26, 2014')` to insert a specified date. Is there any way to insert some different time points in a particular day in Mongodb?

Consider session information in a social network. Let my document is like below: `{ "name" : "koushik", "login_time" : "a new time", "logout_time" : "a new time"}`. I want to explicitly mention "a new time" in mongo shell.

Comment: It's very hard to understand your problem. Do you want to have on time per document? Or one document with time series in it?

Comment: Consider session information in a social network. Let my document is like below: `{ "name" : "koushik", "login_time" : "a new time", "logout_time" : "a new time"}`. I want to explicitly mention `"a new time"` in mongo shell. I think now you can under now what I wanted to say :)

Comment: Would be best if you could use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34507878/edit) link to include those details in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, you have, in MongoShell, to use `ISODate` object:

```
test> db.test.insert({new_date: ISODate("1977-05-25")})
test> db.test.find()
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5682590a09833d813d33dd0c"),
  "new_date": ISODate("1977-05-25T00:00:00Z")
}
```

Comment: It is ok, but it doesn't serve my purpose. It will always show the time `12:00:00 AM UTC`, only the date will vary. I want to enter time manually and right now looking for some data type for the time variable.

Comment: You can set the time on ISODate: `new_date: ISODate("1977-05-25T13:23:42Z")` Is it what you want? If not, please provide an example of the output you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Use update for maintaining login/logout info in session for your application.

```
   db.socialnetworksession
    .find({'name':'koushik'})
    .update(
    { $set: {'login_time': new Date(), 'logout_time': new Date()} },
     function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            cb( err, null );
        }
        cb( null, result );
    });
```